# Shared storage for Xen based cluster that allows I/O control

Tags: xen, shared-storage

I am looking for a solution that will allow me to control I/O usage for my home Xen based cluster. Basically what I need is a way to limit or scale domUs (VMs) disk throughput. E.g. setup:
 - VM1
      volume1 250MBps
      volume2 50MBps
 - VM2
      volume1 100MBps

As far as I know I can use block devices like ceph RADOS or LVM, but what solution can you guys suggest for disk I/O control and scalability?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your storage device? Is this an external disk array? Some of them allow to create multiple RAID groups, virtual disks or even LUNs with different I/O priority.

Comment: Hi Sam,

I am looking for a solution to allow me to set different io bandwidth limits per array and if possible per process. Priorities or weights is no good.